# Are trial SSL certificates enough for signing the firefox extension file?

Tags: firefox, ssl-certificate, code-signing, xpi

Good afternoon everyone!

As you may know, many companies that sell SSL certificates offer free trial certificates (that usually expire in 30 or 50 days). StartCom is the exception - [they give](http://www.startssl.com/?app=1) 1-year free SSL Class 1 certificates.

The question is: are these certificates enough for me to sign my Firefox extension? Note: I'm not asking if these are *good* for the task - I want to discuss only the physical possibility of code signing the xpi file with these free certificates.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "physical possibility"? Why don't you just use a self-signed cert?

Comment: You can't use self-signed certificate with Firefox extensions, because users won't be able to install it (clearly, they don't have you as a certificate authority).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a code signing certificate and not an SSL certificate to sign an add-on.  None of the ones you listed will work.

Answer (score 0):

I have not heard of the "trials" you are talking about, but if they are legitimate certificates then they will work. I would recommend reading the [Certificate Authority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) and the [Public key infrastructure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure) articles on Wikipedia.

Comment: As an example of trial certificate - look at this VeriSign page:

http://www.verisign.com/ssl/buy-ssl-certificates/free-ssl-certificate-trial/

Comment: Thank you Dmitriy. I would give VeriSign's trial a try.

Comment: Or the others. Don't just shop by price, read the fine print and google around.

Answer (score 0):

You can sign anything with any certificate provided you have the private key.

Whether the certificate is valid is another issue.